# Python: Pandas Module - Nested IF Statement that Fills in NaN (Empty Values) in a Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, null

I've created a function that tests multiple IF statements given the data in the 'Name' column.

Criteria 1: If 'Name' is blank, return the 'Secondary_Name'. However, if 'Secondary_Name' is also blank, return the 'Third_Name'.

Criteria 2: If 'Name' == 'GENERAL', return the 'Secondary_Name'. However, if 'Secondary_Name' is also blank, return the 'Third_Name'

Else: Return the 'Name'

```
def account_name(row):
    if row['Name'] == None and row['Secondary_Name'] == None:
        return row['Third_Name']

    elif row['Name'] == 'GENERAL':
        if row['Secondary_Name'] == None:
            return row['Third_Name']

    else:
        return row['Name']
```

I've tried == None, == np.NaN, == Null, .isnull(), == '', == '0'.

Nothing seems to replace the empty values to what I want.

Edit:

[Example of DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haimj.png)

Comment: can you provide us with a sample df?

Comment: Example provided in original post: 'Example of DF'

Answer (score 0):

Depending on column dtype, NULLs dont interact well with NaN for whatever reason.
None would mean that the field is blank, which it is not since you have "a value" for a given dtype.

The simple way to ensure you can identify NaNs is to see if the field is equal to itself

```
def isNaN(value):
if value != value: 
    return True
else:
    return False
```

And to provide an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ClientId':[1,2,3,4] , 'SomeNULLs':['main','main',None,None], 'NewNULLs':[1,None,0,1]})

df['Test'] = df.NewNULLs.apply(isNaN)
```

The resulting dataset should be

```
   ClientId SomeNULLs  NewNULLs   Test
0         1      main       1.0  False
1         2      main       NaN   True
2         3      None       0.0  False
3         4      None       1.0  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['a', 'GENERAL', None],'Secondary_Name':['e','f',None], 'Third_Name':['x', 'y', 'z']})

    Name    Secondary_Name  Third_Name
0   a       e               x
1   GENERAL f               y
2   None    None            z
```

Since you are writing the function in python, you can use is None

```
def account_name(row):

    if (row['Name'] is None or row['Name'] == 'GENERAL') and (row['Secondary_Name'] is None):
        return row['Third_Name']

    elif row['Name'] is None or row['Name'] == 'GENERAL':
        return row['Secondary_Name']

    else:
        return row['Name']

df['Name'] = df.apply(account_name, axis = 1)
```

You get

```
    Name    Secondary_Name  Third_Name
0   a       e               x
1   f       f               y
2   z       None            z
```

You can get same output using pandas and nested np.where

```
cond1 = (df['Name'].isnull()) | (df['Name'] == 'GENERAL')
cond2 = (cond1) & (df['Secondary_Name'].isnull())
np.where(cond2, df['Third_Name'], np.where(cond1, df['Secondary_Name'], df['Name']))
```

Comment: Dear Vaishali,

Thank you for the function provided above. However, when I tested it, the first IF statement didn't return the Third_Name. 

    if (row['Name'] is None or row['Name'] == 'GENERAL') and (row['Secondary_Name'] is None):
        return row['Third_Name']

Comment: Its working fine with the example df I created. Can you post your sample df on the question, not as an image?

Comment: Vaishali,

Does it make a difference if I use the df.apply on a new column? For instance, 

df['Target_Col'] = df.apply(account_name, axis=1) as opposed to df['Name']...

My target col doesn't return the ['Third_Name'] during the first TRUE condition.

Comment: That should not make any difference because your are still apply the function on original df but assigning the result to a new column

Comment: I figured. I'm not sure why when I export the DataFrame, there is still null values in the new column. All of which fall under the first condition and should return 'Third_Name' Info.